# How to change property in DOM and save back to model for use in separate view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I creating a small single-page Angular app. I have the main view in which every item is visible. I need to allow the user to "favorite" an item and have that item show on the other two views. The user may also "unfavorite" the item from any of the three views, essentially removing it from the other two views (only showing in main view.)

I *think* I'm able to change the model using the checkbox, but I can't tell, as it's not updating in the external JSON. I'd like to find a way to save the view change to the model, and then save the model so that it's persistent across all views.

Here's the markup:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isFavorited"></input></label>
```

The controller requests the model as JSON:

```
[   
   {
        "isFavorited": true,
        "name": "Ford Taurus",
        "vendor": "Hertz"
    }
]
```

I've looked at $watch, ng-change, services, directives, etc. I think I'm misunderstanding a fundamental part of Angular. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I would suggest you to create a plunker or a jsfiddle to show us your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the isolated scopes. When you create a new controller inside of your main controller, or next to your main controller, each of them have their own scope. A child scope can see his parent scope, but it is in read-only mode.

There is 2 solution to your problem. You could use the rootScope to store the items and add functions in the rootScope to edit this array. This is a bad design.

The real Angular way to do what you want to do is to use services. A service is shared by all the controllers and even persist between views. The service will hold the data and give you access to it via methods.

This service would do the job :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('FavoritesService', function() {
  var items = [{
        "isFavorited": false,
        "name": "Ford Taurus",
        "vendor": "Hertz",
        "id" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "isFavorited": false,
        "name": "Honda Civic",
        "vendor": "Hertz",
        "id" : 2
    },
    {
        "isFavorited": false,
        "name": "Ford F150",
        "vendor": "Other",
        "id" : 3
    }];

    return {
      getItems: function() {
        return items;
      },
      addItem: function(item) {
        var currentIndex = items.length + 1;
        item.id=currentIndex;
        items.push(item);
      },
      toggleFavorite: function(id) {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          if (id == items[i].id) {
            items[i].isFavorited = !items[i].isFavorited;
            break;
          }
        }
      },
      getFavorites: function() {
        var fav = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          if (items[i].isFavorited) {
            fav.push(items[i]);
          }
        }
        return fav;
      }
    }
  });
```

This service allow you do get the data, toggle the favorite flag or add new items.

You will then use your controller to create a link between the view and the data :

```
$scope.getItems = function() {
  return FavoritesService.getItems();
}

$scope.toggleFavorite = function(id) {
  return FavoritesService.toggleFavorite(id);
}
```

Finally, you can iterate on the data with something like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in getItems()">{{item.name}} - {{item.isFavorited}}
  <button ng-click="toggleFavorite(item.id)">Toggle favorite</button>
</div>
```

I made a plunker that show you how to use it. As you will notice, i added an id in the items to help me identifying them but you could do without it. In the plunker, you can see 3 controllers that share the same data. The child controller only display the favorites and allow you to add new items. It shows you how much control you get from a service.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/qiVc2l)

Good luck!

Comment: This seems like a super-viable solution. My app is a small prototype, so I combined the data into a large object and attached it to $rootScope to persist the model changes across views. Thanks so much for the detailed answer and Plunkr. I'll loop back around and try this solution once I meet my deadline. Thanks again!